# how add new criteria for search tickets on itop

Tags: php, itil

I have created an extension that adds a new field of type AttributeEnumSet to the Person class, now I want to filter the tickets (incidents) by my new field, adding it to the "add new criteria" list on the Search for Incident Objects View, however I can't find where I should add my new search criteria.

[image: List of criterias on Search for Incident Objects View - iTop]

Answer (score 1):

By default, all fields are not available in the filter view. You need to add it to available ones.
In your object datamodel (I suppose UserRequest based on your screenshot).

You need to add your new field in presentation > search :

```
<class id="UserRequest" _delta="merge">
    <presentation>
        <search>
            <item id="FIELD_ID" _delta="define><!-- Choose your ID-->
                <rank>99</rank><!-- Choose your rank -->
            </item>
        </search>
    </presentation>
</class>
```

Then compile with toolkit or setup and it should be good !